Find all positive integers $k$ for which, for any $a,b,c$ the inequality $k(ab+bc+ac) \geq 5(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ holds, $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle
The question

Determine all positive integers $k$ for which, for any positive numbers $a, b$, and $c$, which verify the inequality $k(ab + bc + ac) \geq 5(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)$ there is a triangle with side lengths $a, b$ and $c$.

My idea
We know that if $a,b,c$ are the lengths of a triangle, then we have the inequality:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ < 2(ab+bc+ca)$$ which makes $$5(a^2+b^2+c^2)<10(ab+bc+ca)$$ this making $k>10 \Rightarrow k\geq 11$
Is my rationament correct? Also, how can I demonstrate the inequality? I know it as a propriety and I also have to show it now...I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Just to clarify, is it given that a,b,c are the sides of a triangle in the original question? It seems as though this is the case but I want to be sure as it will affect the answer.

@RedFive Yes, a,b,c are the sides of a triangle.

OK thanks. That means you can use the triangle inequality which is a big help.

@JulioDiEgidio Can you look at the edit i made??? Sorry for my misspelling. Also, how can i demonstrate this propriety

At first glance, it doesn’t seem like any theorem (like the one you mention) that says “If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the sides of a triangle, then [statement involving $k$] is true” can help you prove “If there are numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ for which [statement involving $k$] is true, then $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the sides of a triangle.” I might be misreading your question, but it looks like you are trying to use something like the converse of a theorem to help prove the theorem.

@SteveKass I think i didnt made myself missunderstood. I dont know how to demonstrate that $$a^2+b^2+c^2\ < 2(ab+bc+ca)$$. Also is my other affirmations involving the fact that $k\geq 11$ correct? Thank you!

I don’t quite understand your logic. Your reasoning shows that, rather, $k\le 10$. But you didn’t show “$2(ab + bc + ac) \geq a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2\implies$ there is a triangle with side lengths $a, b$ and $c$” anyway.
For me the answer seems to be $$k=5.$$
If $k<5$, then $k(ab + bc + ac) \geq 5(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)$ never holds, as $ab + bc + ac \le a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2$ for positive $a,b,c$.
If $k=5$, then $k(ab + bc + ac) \geq 5(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)$ turns into $ab + bc + ac \geq a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2$. Since for positive $a,b,c$ holds $ab + bc + ac \le a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2$, we have $ab + bc + ac = a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2$. Or, $a=b=c$. Obviously, there is such triangle.
If $k=6$, then we have $$6(ab + bc + ac) \geq 5(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2).$$
Let us prove that this inequality holds for any $a,b,c$ such that $a=2c$, $b=c$. It turns into $$6(2c^2+c^2+2c^2)\ge5(4c^2+c^2+c^2)$$
$$6\cdot5c^2\ge5\cdot6c^2.$$
This is always true. But these $a,b,c$ don’t form a triangle!
If $k>6$, then the similar argument can be made. Take $a=2c$, $b=c$, then $k(ab + bc + ac) \geq 5(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)$ turns into $nc^2\ge30c^2$, where $n>30$.
SIDE NOTE. If we change the inequality in the problem from $k(ab + bc + ac)\ge 5(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)$ into $k(ab + bc + ac)>5(a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2)$ then $k=6$ will as well suffice. The inequality will turn into
$$5a^2-(6b+6c)a+(5b^2+5c^2-6bc)<0$$
So $a$ is less than the greater root of the LHS:
$$\begin{align} a&< \frac{3b+3c+\sqrt{9b^2+9c^2+18bc-25b^2-25c^2+30bc}}5\\&= \frac{3b+3c+\sqrt{48bc-16b^2-16c^2}}5 \\&= \frac35(b+c)+\frac45\cdot\sqrt{3bc-b^2-c^2}.\tag1 \end{align} $$
Let us prove $$\sqrt{3bc-b^2-c^2}\le \frac{b+c}2.\tag2$$ Square it:
$$12bc-4b^2-c^2\le b^2+c^2+2bc$$
$$10(b-c)^2\ge0.$$ This is always true. So, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get that $$a< \frac35(b+c) + \frac25(b+c)=b+c.$$ Similarly, we get $b<a+c$ and $c<a+b$. So, there is such triangle.
If $k\ge 7$ though, again the same counterexample as in the main reasoning works.

thank you so much for you answer. I saw that propriety in my math book and i thought of using it...i was wondering how can i demonstrate it, but it seems my idea wasnt corect. Thanks again!
